# EtwGetTraceLoggerHandle not found when running Cargo

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

When I run Cargo with any option, I see the following error:

> The entry point to EtwGetTraceLoggerHandle was not found in ntdll.dll

Sorry for my bad translation. The original:

> Точка входа в процедуру EtwGetTraceLoggerHandle не найдена в библиотеке DLL ntdll.dll"

What is the reason? My system is Windows XP 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust isn't ([currently](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1061)) supported on Windows XP.